# Validate if a type is loaded in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to determine if a type is already loaded in PowerShell. Example code below:

```
try {
    $httpHandler = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler
} catch {
    Write-Output -InputObject "Loading type.."
    Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Net.Http"
} # This works OK, but not ideal

# Example 1 -- check if the type is loaded
$types = Get-TypeData
if ($types | Where-Object {$_.TypeName -eq "System.Net.Http"}) {
    Write-Output -InputObject "Loaded"
} else {
    Write-Output -InputObject "Not loaded"
}
# The above returns 'Not loaded' in all cases

# Example 2 -- check if the type is loaded
[Type]::GetType("System.Net.Http", $false)
# Returns no output
```

Is there a way to check if a type is loaded/imported before calling `Add-Type`? There is no `Get-Type` Cmdlet that I can find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search for loaded types like this:

```
[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() |
    ForEach-Object {$_.GetTypes()} |
    Where-Object Name -eq 'FileInfo'
```

Which gives output like this:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name     BaseType                
-------- -------- ----     --------                
True     True     FileInfo System.IO.FileSystemInfo
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do it is with the [`-as` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_type_operators?view=powershell-7.2):

```bash
if (-not ('System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler' -as [type])) {
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Net.Http
}

[System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler]
```